# laravel redirection to previous page after login

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I have a view (URL: /equip-planner) with a form like this:

```
<form action="{{ url('equips') }}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control-sm">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
    <i class="fa fa-btn fa-plus">Create</i>
  </button>    
</form>
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/equip-planner', 'EquipmentController@ep')->name('equip-planner');
Route::resource('equips', 'EquipmentController');
```

Controller Constructor:

```
public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['index', 'show','create','home','ep']]);
    }
```

When I submit my form, it will at first check if the user is logged in since the resource method "store" is not listed in the except list within the controller's constructor. So, if the user is not logged in, he will be redirected to the login page which is just fine.

BUT: After successful login, the user will be redirected to /equips instead of /equip-planner. I guess this is because of the form action `([...]action="{{ url('equips')}}[...])`.

Does anyone have an idea how to change the redirection so the user will be sent back to /equip-planner? ...is it even possible? I think there must be another step back since the steps are: /equip-planner -> /equips -> login -> back to site before, which is /equips ?

EDIT:

My App/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php content:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
  if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
    return redirect()->intended('/home');
  }
  return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
return redirect()->back()
```

And if you want to send msg use **with**

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution:

my form:

```
{{  Form::open( array('route' => 'equip-planner', 'files'=>true,'method'=>'post') )  }}
{{ csrf_field() }}
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control-sm">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
    <i class="fa fa-btn fa-plus">Create</i>
  </button>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Then I added a new route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
  Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::post('/equip-planner', 'EquipmentController@store')->name('equip-planner');
  });
});
```

This is working as intended.